# Why can 'so' be a conjunction, but not 'hence', 'therefore', 'thus', ...?

Tags: conjunctions

While **so** can be an adverb or a conjunction, as the latter, it  can mean 'therefore': see [ODO Definition 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so).  Yet why did ^synonyms of **so** fail to become conjunctions as well?

^Footnote: 'hence', 'therefore', 'thus', and other 'final or illative conjunctions' are listed [here](http://grammarist.com/grammar/conjunctions/), but my grammar teacher insists that they're formally only adverbs.

Comment: Perhaps the answer lies in the etymology. All the adverbs you've given are ultimately related to determiners: *hence* originally meaning 'from this', *therefore* meaning 'for that', and *thus* coming from the same root as *this, that*.

Comment: Your grammar teacher is probly not playing with the full deck of parts of speech. Saying something is an adverb is a confession of ignorance. And if _so_ is a conjunction, so are _hence, therefore,_ and _thus_. There are a lot of [subordinate conjunctions, of various classes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/subordinatingconjunctions.pdf), all of which are adverbial in one way or another; mostly, they all introduce adverbial clauses.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 3):

The seven *coordinating conjunctions* (that is to say words that can be used to connect two independent clauses without one becoming subordinate to the other) are ***for***, ***and***, ***nor***, ***but***, ***or***, ***yet***, and ***so*** (acronym **FANBOYS**). Conjunctions like ***although*** and ***because*** are *subordinating conjunctions*, in that they make the clause that follows them depend on the rest of the sentence for their meaning.

Conjunctions, whether coordinating or subordinating, can happily be inserted between two clauses with no more punctuation than a comma. Sticklers for punctuation would tell you that this is not true of ***therefore***, which is not a connector between two clauses and which should be preceded by a semicolon or a full stop when it begins a new clause. The word ***therefore*** is a *conjunctive adverb*. You can see that it behaves like an adverb when it occurs in the middle of a clause: "*It was cold and I therefore stayed indoors*". Here it answers the question *why* in relation to the verb *stayed*. You might choose to place ***therefore*** before the subject *I* and it would continue to play the same role, but it cannot replace the conjunction ***and***. You need at least a semicolon: "*It was cold; therefore I stayed indoors*".

Comment: Please provide an example using *so* to coordinate but not subordinate so the OP will understand how this can be. Bonus points for coordinating actual noun phrases like *and, but, or, nor* can instead of mere clauses, since there can be no question of subordination then. (NOTE: FANBOYS is a myth, you realize.)

Comment: @tchrist I certainly wouldn't wish to claim that FANBOYS embodies an immutable truth. People do use *therefore* as a connector in the same way that they would use *so*, and consequently *therefore* is slowly but surely finding its way into the FANBOYS (*FANBOTYS*?) canon. But as the OP knows, *therefore* is not in every context a *synonym* for *so*, in the sense that *therefore* can be used as an adverb of manner, whereas *so* can't (*cf* "*It was cold and I so stayed indoors*").

Comment: @*therefore can be used as an adverb of manner, whereas so can't* -- "You are doing it wrongly, do it so. *[demonstrates]*" "So end all tyrants". "It is forbidden to take bribes while so employed".

Comment: @Greybeard Spot on - you are _so_ right!

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of the difference:
When the ‘so’ in a sentence between two independent clauses could otherwise be replaced with ‘so that’ or ‘in order to’ (identifying a closely-linked causal relationship) then it is doing the job of a subordinator: “She creamed the butter with the sugar so (that) the batter would be well-blended and smooth.”

But when the ‘so’ is used between two independent clauses not intending that same (in order to) relationship, it is functioning as a coordinator: “The movie theater was closed, so my sister and I went bowling instead.”